# Unable to access hosted company website from the company's LAN, ok from outside

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, active-directory

In my company the LAN is under a Windows domain called `mycompany.com`.

We also have a website `www.mycompany.com` which is hosted elsewhere. From outside our LAN the website is reachable, while from our LAN I get the following error:

```
10061 - Connection refused
Internet Security and Acceleration Server
```

If I try to ping the address `www.mycompany.com` from outside our LAN I see it actually resolves to a different symbolic name `blog.othercompany.com`, then I get its actual IP `1.2.3.4`.

On our DNS under Forward lookup zones / mycompany.com I set a new host `www` and assigned it the IP address `1.2.3.4`. Then I can ping `www.mycompany.com` from any PC in our domain but I still can't reach the website.

So I tried a different thing: instead of defining a host `www`, I defined an **alias** `www` that points to `blog.othercompany.com`, and again I can ping it correctly, but it still doesn't work.

If I don't have an entry for www in the DNS I can't even ping `www.mycompany.com` (obvious, but I had to try).

I've tried doing a test with portqryui, from within our LAN, and I can see ports 80 and 443 are open and listening. I've tried with multiple browsers, to no avail. I can't understand why I can't access the website.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your problem appears to be with ISA not DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem solved itself after a while. I checked again and now it works... I guess joeqwerty was right and the problem was with ISA, maybe it was caching the original DNS request or something.